# Should there be a directive to return to the takeoff runway immediately on a birdstrike at under 4000 ft?

Tags: bird-strike, unpowered, us1549-accident

I live in London and I've wondered what would happen if a Cactus 1549-style birdstrike emergency had happened/were to happen here.

We don't have Canada geese in the UK, but I was just wondering whether the report into the Hudson water landing in 2009 addressed the fact that having the Hudson in proximity actually turned out to be an enormous stroke of good luck.

At LHR planes mainly take off to the west because the winds are westerlies most of the time, but whether east or west there is no comparable body of water in event of double engine-loss at low altitude. In the case of a takeoff to the east you'd see the Thames, but that river, although pretty wide, has many many bridges, quite a lot of river traffic, and meanders a lot.

There are no doubt hundreds of other airports where you don't have a large body of water in proximity (a broad, bridgeless river, large lake, sea or something else).

I'm aware that doing a 180-degree turn with no power is very bad news indeed, since you start to lose both altitude and kinetic energy immediately. I'm also aware that total loss of power on takeoff is extremely rare!

But at airports without a resource like the Hudson should the protocol be that in the event of a birdstrike under, say, 4000 ft, after takeoff you immediately turn around to return to the takeoff runway, without even trying to assess the damage? I've watched a few videos about the "lessons learnt" after Cactus 1549, but no-one has ever said this was one of the conclusions, let alone that such a protocol was established.

The reason why I mention London is partly because I live here, but also because it is a huge, extensive city: there are no doubt places where a crash landing might be attempted (including some of our parks), but a takeoff to the east experiencing a Cactus 1549-type emergency would almost certainly result in substantial loss of life on the ground as well as any fatalities of those on board... unless it headed back immediately.

Comment: Good question, and ripe for a lively discussion, but I don't think it's quite specific enough for a single correct answer.  I think you have a chance of the question being remaining open if you were to zero in on something specific, perhaps along the lines of your suggested 4000' break point.  I.e. "is there a typical cut-off altitude between low altitude loss of power and high altitude loss of power, and how do emergency procedures differ?"  (immediate forced landing versus restart attempts)  Surmising over potential outcomes on ground impact is pure speculation, and therefore unanswerable.

Comment: ... holding my VTC for now.  P.S. is your user name a play on Mickey Mouse?  I like it either way!

Comment: @MichaelHall Just for the record, I hope my question will be allowed to stand, and that lively discussion is what I was hoping for. Obviously the main focus is on what would indeed happen, with the current directives and training: as I understand it, pilots' training is generally NOT to react precipitately in any situation. Could this be an exception? Yes, my handle is, inter alia, an allusion to my lack of expertise in this and many other domains. PS not sure what "VTC" means... !

Comment: Very well then, but if you have been a member here for as long as you have you ought to know by now that discussion is definitely frowned upon.  There are lots of other venues to chat about possible outcomes, but if you won't narrow it to a specific answerable question then I'm afraid I will join with the inevitable votes to close that I anticipate coming along...

Comment: OK... I'll make it specific to the 4000 ft idea...

Comment: P.S.  VTC=Vote To Close.

Comment: "should there be" is opinion based. please ask a question that looks for a factual answer.

Comment: The uncomfortable fact is that, after passing v1 and until quite a bit of altitude is gained, a dual engine failure will almost surely result in a severe accident. There's no directive that can prevent this type of accident.

Comment: According to Wikipedia, in the US alone there are 13,000 bird strikes each year. That means there have been about 169,000 bird strikes since the Miracle on the Hudson - again, that's the US only. None of those 169,000 flights has met a similar fate. Most would have even continued to the destination, quite possibly not realising the strike happened until they saw blood on the airframe after the flight. There is no need for a directive like you propose.

Comment: @Ben That puts it in some perspective, indeed.

Comment: @mikerodent Let's make the impossible turn mandatory. What a brilliant idea. Not very safe, but quite exiting. I personally watched a plume of smoke rise over the city as a 747 crashed into a high rise full of people, killing hundreds. It was on its way back to the runway it had taken off from. It could have attempted a water landing in any one of a number of large open bodies of water along its path, but didn't. Rules are inherently complacent. They wouldn't have saved the day here.

Comment: @Berend Strange hostility. Have you not understood my question? I was specifically, quite specifically, asking about cities where there are no such open bodies of water.

Comment: @mikerodent No hostilities intended at all. Maybe I just choose my words wrong. Sorry about that.  It's meant as just a picture of the abstraction, no more. Even in a world full of houses, it still limits the options. There is so many different possible reasons to loose thrust while climbing out of a take off, that returning to the runway of origin and thus choosing to accept the thrust loss as permanent, seems like a very harsh and somewhat fatalistic decision.

Answer (score 4):

You cannot develop a directive for each and every type of emergency. Each type of emergency need different response that is difficult to anticipate them all.

Let’s say in case of bird strike in your proposal if you mandate that immediate return is mandatory, what if the engines are running fine and there is traffic behind you? Wouldn’t it more safe to coordinate with ATC for return to airport?

Hence it is best to leave a room to a well-trained captain to assess damage and best course of action to them. Anyway they have excellent training both in theory and flight-sim. Lesson learned from flight 1549 can be added to their training to increase awareness.

Answer (score 3):

In my opinion there should never be a "directive" mandating that an aircraft return to the takeoff runway after a bird strike (or any other catastrophic circumstance that renders the aircraft unable to continue flying) no matter what its altitude is.

There are far too many variables involved to limit the Captain's discretion regarding the course of action that should be followed.

For example:

1. The actual altitude (above or below 4000 ft.) where the aircraft became unable to continue flying;
2. The existing weather (the crew may not even be able to visualize a course reversal) and even with modern navigation avionics (assuming the crew could not see the ground or airport) the time element involved in inputting course data back to the airport could make that impractical;
3. Other air traffic taking off and landing on the same or parallel runways (becoming opposite direction traffic);
4. More variables too numerous to mention.

In the extremely rare situation that your question refers to, the course of action the Captain should choose would always be based on an infinite number of existing variables that cannot be anticipated with enough certainty to develop a mandatory, pre-planned directive.

Comment: I'm not in the industry, so apologise for any ignorance. I had always thought pilots did always have some kind of window to return to the takeoff runway in the event of an emergency after takeoff, which would obviously be conditional on the tower successfully instructing any plane waiting to take off on that runway to taxi off it quickly. But I suppose planes don't have a "reverse", so that might be tricky.

Comment: @mikerodent: based on your question my answer assumes you were asking about an aircraft that was rendered unable to continue to fly (e.g. total engine failure,  etc.) and needed to do an immediate return to the takeoff airport. Nevertheless, a "directive" (i.e. mandatory course of action) to be taken that fits all potential circumstances is not practical. There are emergency procedures (like trying to restart the engines, etc.) that would be considered depending on the overall circumstances. But too many variables to mandate a single choice of pilot action.